# InvalidOperationException delegation UI Thread C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml

I'm getting `InvalidOperationException`. This code is running in a thread. I've delegate it to the UI thread to handle the UI. Is the problem occuring because of my resources?

```
BitmapImage logo = new BitmapImage();
logo.BeginInit();
logo.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/LiarDice;component/" + imagePath);
logo.EndInit();
currentGuessDice.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
new Action(delegate()
{
    currentGuessDice.Source = logo;
}));
```

I changed my code slightly a little and now the error changes to:

```
Part URI cannot end with a forward slash.
```

New Code:

```
currentGuessDice.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                new Action(delegate()
                {
                    BitmapImage logo = new BitmapImage();
                    logo.BeginInit();
                    logo.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/LiarDice;component/" + imagePath);
                    logo.EndInit();
                    currentGuessDice.Source = logo;
                }));
```

Comment: What makes you think it's related to multithreading, or threading (UI) at all? The exception clearly states this is URI parsing error.

Comment: It was having InvalidOperationException before I edited the code and placed the entire initialization inside the Dispatcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides that your `imagePath` variable my be `null`, the problem in your original code is that you create a BitmapImage in a thread other than the UI thread, and then use it in the UI thread.

BitmapImage is a `DispatcherObject`, which means that is has [thread affinity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject?view=net-5.0). Since it is also a `Freezable`, you can freeze it in order to make it accessible to threads other than the one in which it was created:

```
var logo = new BitmapImage(
    new Uri("pack://application:,,,/LiarDice;component/" + imagePath));

logo.Freeze(); // here

currentGuessDice.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => currentGuessDice.Source = logo));
```

Comment: Oic. That was what I'm thinking. I've since placed the code within the ui thread. What would be better? Initializing the BitmapImage within the UI thread or using .Freeze() ?

Comment: Creating and freezing the BitmapImage would be better, because it would keep that work from the UI thread. That's why you have a background thread in the first place. However, if it's not a very large bitmap, you will hardly notice any difference.